# How to work around server limitations on form size?

Tags: forms

I have a form pretty similar to one you can see on your own sites under http://example.com/admin/people/permissions - that is, rows with checkboxes. A lot of checkboxes. I used this code to count them:

```
console.log(jQuery(':input').length)
```

Now, when page contains 1858 of them, everything works all right. But one more row makes it 1874. 16 fields per row is not much, and I do need to have all these rows on one page, for draggable to work. And after all, about 115 rows (plus some non-row config) does not sound *that* big, if you think about it. Sadly, it is too much for my server.

If there is one row too much, request is sent, but it reaches the server stripped from it's POST data. This makes Drupal to just re-send form page, as if user just hit refresh on his browser.

Is there any Drupal method to go around it and send data in parts? Or only send rows that was actually interacted with?

**Note**

If I'll add enough roles to push built-in permission page over about 2000 inputs, it exhibit exactly the same behavior.

I know I can increase allowed sizes server side, I even found how. But I'm looking for a way to avoid that need.

Comment: So how many checkboxes are there on the permissions page? It would be interesting if there are even more of them there, as some sites have.

Comment: You _could_ take over the submission and just ajax in the changed state, but that's a lot of work for something that should "just work". What's the size in bytes of the $_POST request before it gets rejected?

Comment: @Letharion It's not the permission page, but it's my form that's pretty much a clone of it, plus draggable. And with similar purpose. I referenced perm page because everyone knows it and my own is hardly different. Weight field couldn't be the reason of my problem. Removing it only increases number of rows before fail, that's all. And creating enough roles does, in fact, break perm page as well.

Comment: Right, so what I'm getting at is, is there another form, with as many inputs, that does not exhibit the same problem. Such as the permission form? Also check this: http://www.suhosin.org/stories/configuration.html and see if any of the defaults max values ring a bell. (Max length 1MB, max vars 1000 and so on)

Comment: @Letharion question updated

Comment: I'd inspect the $_POST more closely then, for both forms ideally. Exactly how many bytes is it before things fall over? How many variables are in there? And what php modules are enabled? Specifically, is suhosin installed? (There's phpinfo() output somewhere under admin/status/reports/php or some such, though you probably knew that already)

Comment: @Letharion that part is now inspected by admins. Here in this question I'm interested what can be done from Drupal side - because I can alter Drupal side on my own, and because not everybody can change his server's config